# Using g.message() in css file

Tags: css, grails, internationalization

Is there any way/workaround to use grails native i18n `g:message`, or `g.message()` in .css file? In Grails project, of course.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be a plugin that would allow you to add gsp tags to your css (also supports js):

http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-arse

This sounds like what you're looking for, you should then be able to embed g:message tags.

Comment: Thaks for quick response, GSParse looks useful, but have anybody made it run in CSS? I'm not able to make it, I'll give one more try to investigate https://github.com/nerdErg/GSParseTestApp, to find what I'm doing wrong. Is there some more documentation on GSParse insteand of official pointed from http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-arse ? Thanks

Comment: Hi Vaclav, from having a quick look at your code, it doesn't look like you're using the resource plugin, so the entry in URLMappings might not work. Looks like you're using grails 1.3.4, which doesn't have the resources directory i don't think. It might be worth changing the link in your URLMappings to "/css/**"(controller: 'script', action: 'parse') and see if that works?